# blurry images after upload

Tags: image, channel-images, resize

Using Channel Images to upload images. They are uploaded at full size and no resizing is set. When I save the image off the browser and open it Photoshop, they are back to original sharpness. Also, I have an image zoom installed and when you hover the image in the magnified area is sharp. Is this EE or a browser issue? It seems like it IS being resized somewhere along the way...

After / Before

[image]

Comment: Do you have some template code to share or a site we can look at?

Comment: Have you checked the quality settings in the custom field Channel images settings, and also check to see if the image size attribute and/or CSS is not doing anything it shouldn't.

Comment: I'll have my programmer check on the CSS. I know the CI settings are at 100.

Answer (score 1):

Check the image zoom plugin's settings to make sure it is not applying a filter. Also, check your CSS. It could be that a blurring filter effect is being applied ([see here](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/)).